# How can I see search result suggestions in Vivaldi's address bar?

Tags: vivaldi

I am trying to use Vivaldi, because I am having issues with Firefox on Manjaro.

I think I am doing something wrong/stupid, because I don't seem to be able to search using Vivaldi's address bar.

When I start typing in the address bar, I see suggested bookmarks, history but I don't see search suggestions from my default search engine.

**Update**
Sorry I didn't realize that I needed to provide more info.  I guess because this stuff works out of the box on firefox I always took it for granted.  Anyway hope the following info helps:

- I use google search

[image]

Comment: Have you tried looking at [Vivaldi's help about searching](https://help.vivaldi.com/desktop/tools/search/)? It should be fairly simple... and there are a ton of options of how you can use search, and built-in or custom search engines. Vivaldi's biggest strength is customisability, but "the simple way" should still work out of the box.

Comment: Yes I've been going through settings, etc and looking through their website.  I agree the simple way should just work out of the box.

Comment: Hard to help you without knowing what your default search engine is, whether it supports search suggestions by third parties (google doesn't play nice, for instance), and what your search settings are. Try changing default search engines, and see if search suggestions work for others?

Comment: @AmosM.Carpenter I updated the question hopefully that's better

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google has a history of not letting its search suggestions play nice with non-Google products, so this may break at some point. However, the following settings should let you use search suggestions with the google search engine in Vivaldi. (Works for me in Vivaldi 5.5.2770.3.)

Firstly, make sure search suggestions are turned on in settings (`vivaldi://settings/search/`) for the address field or the search field, depending on where you want to use it. Based on your privacy preferences, optionally check the "Only when using search engine nickname" box.

[image: Vivaldi search suggestion settings]

Next, paste the following URL into the "Suggest URL" field for your google search: https://www.google.com/complete/search?client=chrome&q=%s

Mine looks like this (but I use the `.com.au` URL elsewhere, yours may be different):

[image: Vivaldi suggest URL field]

Once that's done, you can use the keyword search using the search engine's nickname, e.g. "g vivaldi google search suggestions", to search with suggestions enabled.

If you're not worried about privacy, you could try leaving the "only when using search engine nickname" field unchecked, and it should work without the "g" at the beginning.